# "washer and dryer" vs "washers and dryers"

Tags: grammar

It is a shared laundry facility where money is needed to use the washer and dryer.

vs

It is a shared laundry facility where money is needed to use the washers and dryers.

Which one is correct and why? How do you call this rule in English grammar?

Comment: *How many* washers and *how many* driers...?

Answer (score 4):

Why do you feel like one is correct and the other isn't?

You have provided two valid ways to say pretty much the same thing.

> It is a shared laundry facility where money is needed to use the washer and dryer.

That sentence works; it implies I'll need some money to do a load of laundry.

> It is a shared laundry facility where money is needed to use the washers and dryers.

That sentence also works, although it further implies there is more than one washer and dryer in the facility.

You could also use an indefinite article:

> It is a shared laundry facility where money is needed to use a washer and dryer.

All three of those are grammatical, although the plural form wouldn't work if the facility only had a single washer and dryer (such as in a small hotel or something).

Of course, the simplest way to say this (at least in the U.S.) is:

> *It's a [laundromat](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/laundromat)*.

Comment: In most laundromats and some "shared laundry facilities"  there are enough washers and dryers that a single person/family might use multiple washers and/or dryers _simultaneously_. If that is the case, plurals are quite appropriate.  If there is only one of each, of course the singular form would be the only appropriate expression.

Comment: In British English, it's a launderette.

Comment: @ssav - Yes, that's one reason I chose the link I decided to use – that dictionary page explicitly mentions that.